# Seleccion value en select y sumar valor seleccionado a input

Tags: javascript, html5

La idea es es que se pueda seleccionar en un input ciertos valores y que el valor seleccionado se le sume a un input. Si se selecciono 100 por ejemplo en el input se le debe sumar 100, luego si selecciono otro valor por ejemplo el 200 se debe quitar el valor antes seleccionado y ahora sumar el el que se selecciono ahora que seria 200.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Ten en cuenta que esta es una comunidad de ayuda en la que se requiere que quien pregunte sea claro exponiendo el problema e indique lo que ha intentado. Tu pregunta no cumple ninguno de esos dos requisitos. No se sabe si quieres que al total que hay se vayan sumando los valores del select o si lo que quieres es cambiarlo, además pones un ejemplo que no ayuda. Si el primer select tenía `3` el valor del input será `3`... si luego se selecciona otro con un valor `5` ¿el input debe valer `5` o debe valer `8`?

Answer (score 0):

Se podria hacer con javascript de esta manera:

```
var select = document.getElementById();//id de el select
var input = document.getElementById();//id del input

select.addEventListener("change", event => {
    input.value = parseInt(input.value) + parseInt(select.value);
});
```

Comment: Parecería que él quiere que los  valores se vayan acumulando en el  `input`, aunque no lo expone de una forma del todo clara.

Comment: si creo que si.